# Is there a way to modify this C++ struct assignment block to work in straight C

Tags: c++, c

The following code resides in a device that will issue a deviceId (LXdeviceInfo) when enumerated through an IrDA sockets connection.  This is only important to explain why I would like to keep the data types as similar as possible, but be able to compile using ansi C

With #includes of windows.h and af_irda.h, the following code compiles with no errors in a C++ compiler, but breaks in a C compiler just below the struct assignment (see ERROR here).  Ideally I would like to initialize the struct member *'ID'* to be an array of characters while keeping it typed just as it is in the original code so I can test the value of LXdeviceInfo just as it would appear when querying it from a call to the device from a PC socket connection.

Is there some way to modify this assignment block to work in straight C?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <af_irda.h>

#define IR_HINT_COMPUTER  0x04
#define IR_HINT_EXT       0x80
#define IR_HINT_OBEX      0x20
#define IR_HINT_IRCOMM    0x04
#define IR_CHAR_ASCII       0
#define PROD_FAMILY_NAME ("product name goes here")

#define uint8_t unsigned char

const struct {
    uint8_t hint1;
    uint8_t hint2;
    uint8_t charset;
    uint8_t ID[sizeof(PROD_FAMILY_NAME)];
} devInfoStorage = 
{
    IR_HINT_COMPUTER | IR_HINT_EXT,   // hint1
    IR_HINT_OBEX | IR_HINT_IRCOMM,    // hint2
    IR_CHAR_ASCII,                    // charset
    PROD_FAMILY_NAME                  // Prod ID string
}; // ERROR here: Invalid initialization type: found 'pointer to char' expected 'unsigned char'

const uint8_t *LXdeviceInfo = (uint8_t *) &devInfoStorage;

/* The size of the device info */
const uint8_t LXdeviceInfoLen = sizeof(devInfoStorage);



void main(void)
{

    #define DEVICE_LIST_LEN    10

    unsigned char DevListBuff[sizeof (DEVICELIST) -
                              sizeof (IRDA_DEVICE_INFO) +
                              (sizeof (IRDA_DEVICE_INFO) * DEVICE_LIST_LEN)];

    int DevListLen = sizeof (DevListBuff);
    PDEVICELIST pDevList;

    pDevList = (PDEVICELIST) & DevListBuff;
         //code continues.
}
```

Comment: Try removing the parentheses from the PROD_FAMILY_NAME.

Comment: As far as I can tell that should be valid C also. Possibly the parenthesis around the string messing it up? Or maybe the array assignment isn't taking because a unsigned char and a char aren't quite matching up.

Comment: @ryyker what about replacing those defines with their `const` and `typedef` equivalents?

Comment: It's `int main(void)`, *not* `void main(void)`. If you have a textbook that told you `void main(void)` is correct, you need to get a better one.

Comment: @KeithThompson - How about the C99 standard "It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters ... or with two parameters ... or in some other implementation-defined manner ". (section 5.1.2.2.1).  It sounds like it can be defined any way it needs to be.

Comment: @ryyker: Definitions other than the two forms defined in the standard are valid *only* if the implementation you're using documents another form, and then *only* for that implementation. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined. (And C++ doesn't permit `main` to have a return type other than `int` at all.) For freestanding implementations, the program's entry point is entirely implementation-defined, and might not even be called `main`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the parentheses around the string literal. The parentheses make the macro expand into an expression that will decay into a pointer type, which makes it not compile in your C compiler. A pointer type cannot be used to initialize an array. Without the parentheses, the string literal is used to initialize the array.

```
#define PROD_FAMILY_NAME "product name goes here"
```

The C standard states that a parenthesized expression takes on the same type as the unparenthesized expression, C.99 §6.5.1 ¶5:

> A parenthesized expression is a primary expression. **Its type and value are identical to those of the unparenthesized expression.** It is an lvalue, a function designator, or a void expression if the unparenthesized expression is, respectively, an lvalue, a function designator, or a void expression.

However, while a string literal is an expression, the converse is not true. Specifically, a string literal in of itself is not a type, but a defined entity. The initialization of arrays makes a specific allowance for a string literal, C.99 §6.7.8 ¶14:

> **An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal**, optionally
>   enclosed in braces.

The other allowed initializers for an array are described in C.99 §6.7.8 ¶16:

> Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace enclosed list of initializers for the elements or named members.

A parenthesized expression is not a string literal, nor a brace enclosed list of initializers.

Comment: Actually, looks like a bug in the C compiler -- the parenthesis are perfectly legal in an initializer, so should not force the compiler to treat it as an expression.  For comparison, it works fine with gcc (mingw)

Comment: maybe #define S ("hello") decays to a ponter ?

Comment: C99 §6.7.8/14-16 say "An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. [...] Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace-enclosed list of initializers for the elements or named members."  That seems to imply that `("blah")` is not a legal initializer, since it's neither a string literal, a brace-enclosed string literal, nor a brace-enclosed list of initializers.

Comment: gcc 4.7.2 has a specific warning for this: "warning: array initialized from parenthesized string constant [-pedantic]"; it appears with `gcc -pedantic -std=cXX`, where `XX` is any of `90`, `99`, `11`.

Comment: Your second sentence isn't quite right. Both `"foo"` and `( "foo" )` are expressions. The difference is that `"foo"` doesn't decay to a pointer in this context, while `( "foo" )` does. (Which is surprising, but it does seem to follow from the wording of the Standard).

Comment: A character literal has type 'array of char' and the decay to pointer only happens in a context where an array is not valid.  So for example `sizeof((("foobar")))` is 7 not `sizeof(char *)` no matter how many extra parentheses are added.  The language in 6.7.8.14 is annoyingly imprecise -- what is a 'character string literal' in this context?  Is something like `char foo[] = "foo" "bar";` legal (taking advantage of string literal concatenation)?

Comment: @ChrisDodd: For your `sizeof` example, the type of the expression is array of `char` up until the expression is used. An array type does not decay in a `sizeof` (one of the 3? exceptions). The decay in my answer refers to the compiler error message.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, thanks for your notes - I agree, from the quoted standards it does look like a bug. I will notify NI of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As `PROD_FAMILY_NAME` is a (constant) string, the compiler expects `ID` to be declared as something like `uint8_t *ID;` as strings are generally represented as pointers to characters in memory in C. See my example here: http://ideone.com/m5ZZl0

To do this with a character array as you have, you need to do a `strcpy` or `memcpy` from the product family name to your `ID` byte array as C doesn't support direct array assignment as far as I know. If the product name will be a variable but isn't going to change and won't go out of scope, I'd recommend using a `uint8_t*`-typed `ID`, but if you need a copy of the name and don't want to dynamically allocate memory you may want to stick with an array (but note that older versions of the C standard don't support non-static-length arrays, either [though there are ways of getting around that with a variable-length array at the end of the struct, but you often have to keep track of the struct size manually in such cases as `sizeof()` will return 0 for such arrays; things like `strlen()` should still work fine, though.)

---

Seems I forgot that, while array assignment isn't allowed, something like `char array[] = "literal string";` still is. (http://ideone.com/vilDOa vs. http://ideone.com/gEC2k2) So my above was a bit pointless, but I do think that dynamically sizing structs isn't all that good of an idea if you want to have an array of such structs, in which case the `char*` method can be a better idea (even if it's just a pointer to an array elsewhere).